# table-cell divs not sizing correctly

Tags: css

My divs that are displayed as table-cells are not sizing correctly. I set the width to 91px but it's rendered at 90.2667px. This is in Firefox, but I haven't tested other browsers.

Here is what comes up when I inspect the element:

```
width       90.2667px
.OrderCell3 → 91px  inline:1
```

As soon as I disable "display:table-cell" it widens to 91px exactly. However I need it to display this way to look the way I want.

Edit: Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKuj5/

Comment: how do you get to knoxw that, and how can that be possible on screen ?

Comment: How about posting a full example of the problem? Better yet, throw in a jsFiddle.net example too.

Comment: @GCyrillus In Firefox, hit Ctrl+Shift+K, then click Inspector, then I click on the cell. This problem is iterated across 8 cells so it looks funky

Comment: @j08691 I added a fiddle to it.

Comment: Do you mean your cell reduces at 90px on screen ?, if so , then try to set width at 91.4px .it should drop down at 91 on screen, this value is then over 90.5 in ff , it should fix it for FF to climb up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see no tables in your code,
Funny, when it is table-data.

It seems like you tried to get a way to make a scrolling table.
If that's so, then reconsider your code , while you can achieve it from a real table.

http://dabblet.com/gist/5648624 it's using em, but it can be px or % .

The trick is , a tfoot clone from thead, so your col layout should stay under header(footer)
The container slides, not tbody.

Comment: Ok this is a much better way to do things than using divs.

Comment: So I rewrote it and I'm back to the same problem, where the cells are misaligned. http://jsfiddle.net/nVyH2/

The table footer, which is positioned absolutely at the top, is slightly off. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: you have to remenber that tfoot has to stay away from scroll bar. try this:.orderlistcontainer tfoot {table-layout:fixed;position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;display: table-header-group;right:1.4em;}

Answer (score 0):

Default tables have some spacing and padding in them.  You'll have to mess with the style of the table to rid the spacing:

```
<table style='width:91px; border-spacing:0px;'>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding:0px;'>
      <div>
        stuff
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, doing this will make your table essentially invisible, which is the same as hiding the cells.  The only way around it, in that case, is to compensate the size of the table by accounting for the border sizing as well.  Table needs to be something like 91px + (cell-padding*2 * numColumns) + table's border-spacing * 2.